# Isotope adding a class to first 3 items (onload, filtered)

Tags: jquery-isotope

I am attempting to add a class to the first 3 items when the layout loads initially and each time it changes dependent on a selected filter.

```
$container.isotope( 'on', 'layoutComplete',
    function( isoInstance, laidOutItems ) {

        // no results
        if ( !laidOutItems.length ) {
            $('.message').fadeIn('slow');
        } else {
            $('.message').fadeOut('fast');
        }

        // add popular class to first 3 items
        $('.item').find('.well').removeClass('popular');
        $('.item:lt(3)').find('.well').addClass('popular');
    }
);
```

The above only affects items that are hard coded on the page.  I am having trouble removing the class from all items in the layout and then adding it to the first 3 filtered items.

Answer (score 0):

You can target the hidden elements and the visible elements using their classes. So first of all you will add and remove a hidden class to filtered elements like this:

```
var itemReveal = Isotope.Item.prototype.reveal;
Isotope.Item.prototype.reveal = function() {
  itemReveal.apply( this, arguments );
  $( this.element ).removeClass('isotope-hidden');
};

var itemHide = Isotope.Item.prototype.hide;
Isotope.Item.prototype.hide = function() {
  itemHide.apply( this, arguments );
  $( this.element ).addClass('isotope-hidden');
};
```

Once you know what's visible and not visible, you will be able to use `:lt(3)').` to your visible items